# html form returning a json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

This is my simple html form that will pass username and password and returns a json array

```
 <form class="form-signin" id="login" method="post" action="/Webservices/0.1/login"">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email id" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id= "password">
  <button  type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >Sign in</button>
     </form>
```

This is my route:

```
router.post('/login',function (req,res) {
    var email           = req.body.email;
    var password        = req.body.password;
    var arrayParam      =  [];
    var emailValidation = emailPattern.test(email);
    arrayParam.push('email','password');
    reqdParams.verifiyRequiredParameters(arrayParam, req.body, function (result) {
        if (result.success == "0") {
            res.json(result);
        }
        else if (email == '' || password == '' ) {
            res.json({'success': '0', 'result': {}, 'errorMessage': "data should not be null"});
        }
        else if (!(emailValidation)) {
            res.json({'success': '0', 'result': {}, 'errorMessage': 'not a valid email'});
        }
        else
        {   password =new Buffer(password).toString('base64');
            var userObject  = {'email':email, 'password': password};
            var  verifyUserQuery  = model.client.prepare("select userId,username,IFNULL(profilePicture,'') as profilePicture,email,password,profileType,IFNULL(profileId,'') as profileId,userType,IFNULL(token,'') as token,deviceName,osType,osVersion,isBlocked,isActive,ofActive,joinedDate from users where email = :email and password=:password");
            model.client.query(verifyUserQuery (userObject ),function(err,rows){
                if(rows.length> 0){
                    if(rows[0].isActive == 1){
                        var userProfile = rows[0];
                        res.json({'success':'1','result':{'message':'Valid User','userProfile':userProfile},'errorMessage':'No'});
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'user is not verified'});
                    }

                }
                else
                    res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'user Invalid'});
            });
        }
    });

});
```

This code will return a json array:

```
{"success":"0","result":{},"errorMessage":"user Invalid"}
```

if `success=0` i want to display error Message in html form.

if  `success-1`  i want to redirect to another page.

how to do this?

Comment: Please show your PHP code. Are you saving this form using AJAX?

Comment: Please post the code and what you have tried so far, so that we can offer best help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var err = {"success":"0","result":{},"errorMessage":"user Invalid"},
    holder = document.getElementById('errorholder');

if(err.success == '0'){
    holder.innerHTML = err.errorMessage;
} else {
    // redirect using window.location
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="errorholder"></div>
```